# Заменить следующую строку значением на основе предыдущего

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> Если у нас значение 1 а следующее (нижнее) 0, то нижнее равно тоже 1
> Если значение 1, а нижнее -1 - ничего не делаем
> Если в строке -1, а следующее ноль, то пишем в следующей -1.

Пробую стандартным методом скопировать значения в столбце `df['1']` но не выходит.

вот [файл](https://dropmefiles.com/9nx0H)

```
df = pd.read_csv('23.csv')
df.columns = ['Date', '1']
```

```
       Date   1
0   4-Jan-00    0
1   5-Jan-00    0
2   6-Jan-00    1
3   7-Jan-00    0
4   10-Jan-00   0
5   11-Jan-00  -1
6   12-Jan-00   0
7   13-Jan-00   0
8   14-Jan-00   1
9   17-Jan-00   0
10  18-Jan-00   0
11  19-Jan-00   0
12  20-Jan-00   0
13  21-Jan-00   1
```

Результат

```
       Date   1
0   4-Jan-00    0
1   5-Jan-00    0
2   6-Jan-00    1
3   7-Jan-00    1
4   10-Jan-00   1
5   11-Jan-00  -1
6   12-Jan-00  -1
7   13-Jan-00  -1
8   14-Jan-00   1
9   17-Jan-00   1
10  18-Jan-00   1
11  19-Jan-00   1
12  20-Jan-00   1
13  21-Jan-00   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Поменяйте в этой колонке `0` на `NA`
2. Используйте функцию `fillna(method='ffill')` чтобы заменить значения `NA` на предыдущие не-`NA` значения в колонке.
3. Поменяйте оставшиеся `NA` обратно на `0`.

Пример кода:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0 ,0, 1, 0]})
df['1'] = df['1'].replace(0, np.NaN).fillna(method='ffill').replace(np.NaN, 0).astype(int)
df['1']
```

Вывод:

```
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7    -1
8    -1
9    -1
10   -1
11    1
12    1
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Приходится ещё шаманить потом с типом данных, чтобы устранить последствия замены на `NA`. Вероятно, можно сделать и как-то проще.

Answer (score 1):

воспользуйтесь методом `replace`:

```
df['1'].replace(0, method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

при ваших исходных данных, получим:

```
         Date  1
0    4-Jan-00  0
1    5-Jan-00  0
2    6-Jan-00  1
3    7-Jan-00  1
4   10-Jan-00  1
5   11-Jan-00 -1
6   12-Jan-00 -1
7   13-Jan-00 -1
8   14-Jan-00  1
9   17-Jan-00  1
10  18-Jan-00  1
11  19-Jan-00  1
12  20-Jan-00  1
13  21-Jan-00  1
```

Comment: О, так и знал, что можно короче сделать )